# How to edit lines inside dat file?

Tags: php

How can I edit lines inside a .dat file using `php`?

.dat file:

```
1|example1|123
2|example2|234
3|example3|345
```

I want to edit `2` and everything next to it. Example output:

```
1|example1|123
2|edited2|234
3|example3|345
```

Comment: What do you mean by "edit". Is this a file on the php server whose contents you want to change? Is this "live" (interactive) editing, or programmatic. Why do you want to use php?

Comment: Post your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
<?php
  $contents = file_get_contents("myfile.dat");
  // if you just need to replace a specific string:
  $newContent = preg_replace("/2\|example/", "2|edited", $contents);
  echo $newContent;
  file_put_contents("myNewFile.dat", $newContent);
?>
```

Output:

```
1|example1|123
2|edited2|234
3|example3|345
```

I wrote it as a new file to prevent accidentally overwriting (better for testing). If you use the same file name, you can "edit", in effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$handle = fopen("file.dat", "r");
$reconstruct = "";

if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

         $linenumber = explode("|", $line, 1);

         if($linenumber == "2")
         {
             $reconstruct .= "2|edited2|234\r\n";
         }else{
             $reconstruct .= $line;
         }
     }
     if (fwrite($handle, $reconstruct) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file";
        exit;
     }
} else {
    echo "Cannot open file";
}
fclose($handle);
```